# The zeros of a trigonometric polynomial

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry

Can we describe the set of zeros of a trigonometric polynomial? A trigonometric polynomial is $\sum a_n e^{inx}$.

How many zeros can trigonometric polynomials have in an interval with the length equal to the period of that polynomial? Can it vanish on an interval?

Comment: Can you give us an example? What exactly do you mean by a trigonometric polynomial?

Comment: Are you considering only finite sums? If so, then I think you are asking can the zero function can be approximated uniformly by Fourier series for which the answer I believe is no.

Comment: @JeremyUpsal  yes I mean finite sums.would you please tell me  a proof?